# How to cascade deletes in Titan DB?

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, cascading-deletes, titan

I want to delete a vertex and all vertexes that point to it where the edges between them are from a set of labels - not necessarily *all* the incoming vertexes.

In a relational database you can configure automatic deletion of related entities using cascading deletes on foreign keys.

Is there a similar configuration expressible in Titan DB or with Gremlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such feature in Titan at this time.  You would have to manage such logic manually as part of your delete of the vertex:

```
g.v(123).in('some','labels','only').remove()
g.v(123).remove()
```

Comment: That's quite succinct nonetheless.

Comment: aha... seems that you have to called 'iterate' when away from Rexster.